# HOG preprocessing normalization

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I don't understand what the purpose is of the preprocessing step in HOG (histogram of oriented gradients). In step 1 we normalize the image using a square-root normalization. What is the advantage of this step? Also we have a block normalization. Are these two steps the same?

Comment: Read [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients#Block_normalization) on the Wikipedia page for HOG. It talks about different forms or normalization explored by two researchers, and concludes "all four methods showed very significant improvement over the non-normalized data." So, that is the reason for the normalization.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy. Normalization is used to remove local light differences. The pattern in dark scene can be same in light scene but the values are different. [2 2 3 3] is one edge from 2 to 3. [4 4 6 6] is basically same edge 2 times first vector. These two vectors are linearly dependent. Normalization is way to find match these vectors which describes the same in different conditions. First vector l2 norm Sqrt( pow(2)+pow(2)+pow(3)+pow(3)) = 5,09   , the second is sqrt(pow(4)+pow(4)+pow(6)+pow(6)) is = 10,19. If you divide each element of first vector by 5,09 and each element of second vector by 10,19 the result is [0.4 0.4 0.6 0.6]. They are describing the same with different light conditions. This is the basics of Algebra. [my blog with cv resources](https://funvision.blogspot.com)